# How do i select the highest number in one column and then search the the id in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select the highest number in one column and then search the the ID in other table?

I have these two tables:

```sql
create table armazens_has_artigos
(
    stockMinimo int not null,
    stockQuantidade int not null,
    idArtigos int not null,
    idArmazens int not null,
    idZonasFisicas int not null

    constraint fk_armazens_has_artigos_idArtigos
        foreign key (idArtigos)
            references artigos (idArtigos) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_armazens_has_artigos_idArmazens
        foreign key (idArmazens)
            references armazens (idArmazens) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_armazens_has_artigos_zonasFisicas_idZonasFisicas
        foreign key (idZonasFisicas)
            references zonasFisicas (idZonasFisicas) on delete cascade
);
```

In this one I need to select the highest `StockQuantidade` and then with the same `id` select in this table the `nome`

```sql
create table artigos 
(
    idArtigos int primary key,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
    descr varchar (45) not null,
    precoCompra float not null,
    precoVenda float not null,
    unidadeRepresentacao varchar (45) not null
);
```

Comment: FYI for something called "Purchase Price" `float` is a terrible data type choice. Money doesn't work well in Base 2 numbers; you *will* suffer rounding issues.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample

Comment: Something like: Stock quantidade maxima -3 on other table nome-joao

Comment: It is not very clear, but perhaps you are seeking a "first in group" solution. Search the internet for that phrase to find examples. And be consistent in your description. You have no column named `id` and it is not good for everyone to guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  nome
FROM artigos
JOIN armazens_has_artigos
  ON armazens_has_artigos.idArtigos = artigos.idArtigos
WHERE armazens_has_artigos.stockQuantidade = (SELECT
  MAX(stockQuantidade)
FROM armazens_has_artigos)
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more then one Artigos matching the criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM artigos
WHERE idArtigos IN
      (
          SELECT idArtigos
          FROM dbo.armazens_has_artigos
          WHERE stockQuantidade =
          (
              SELECT MAX(stockQuantidade)FROM armazens_has_artigos
          )
      );
```